# How to embed a gzipped jquery as base64 in my html page

Tags: javascript, base64

For an embedded webserver I want to make 
-webpage size very small
-embed all javascript / css in one html file

To achieve this, I want to embed my javascript (jquery) with the following steps:
-uglify javscript
-gzipped javascript
-convert to base64 string.

Does anyone know how this works? I tried the following:

data:multipart/x-gzip;base64,H4...(base64 code)

Comment: Does base64 encoding a gzipped document really save any space?

Comment: the best way to find out is trying

Comment: My point was that base64 encoding usually increases the size of a file by 33%, so a 16KB file will become 21KB after encoding in base64. This may cancel out any benefit you would get from gzipping.

Comment: Yes I know that. My uglified javascript goes from 125.9 kB to 40.2 kB bij gzipping. In my case this step would reduce the footprint of my webpage to about 40.2 * 1.33 = 56 kB. Too bad I could not figure out how to include gzipped javascript in my webpage.